# Shall I use json_encode() when returning Array data to be accessed by JQuery AJAX?

Tags: jquery

I was trying to use JQuery AJAX to grab some data retrieved from the database in cakePHP 1.26:

```
 function testing(){
    $user = $this->user->findallbyuser_id("1");
    return $user;
}
```

and here is the output from cakePHP built-in function Debug($user):

```
Array
(
    [user_id] => 1
    [name] => hello  
)
```

Here is the JQuery part:

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: curl,   
      success: function(data){ 
      alert(data); }
});
```

Here is the Alert message:

```
Array <!--0.082-->
```

Later, I found that the Alert message showed me something different after I altered
the code:

```
 function testing(){
    $user = $this->user->findallbyuser_id("1");
    return json_encode($user);
}
```

And here is the new output from the Alert message box:

```
{"user_id":"1","name":"hello"}<!--0.0953-->
```

But I don't know how to print out the data returned from JQuery AJAX in this way:

```
User ID: 1
User name: hello
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON can be thought of as simply a PHP array for JavaScript (it's not that strictly speaking, but it helps to understand).

So to get the value of `user_id` we do the following

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: curl,   
    success: function(data) { 
        alert(data.user_id); 
    }
});
```

Notice how we simply append `.user_id` because thats the key name from the JSON array.

When the PHP script returned the JSON encoded array, `jQuery.ajax` picked it up and popped it into the data variable we defined via `success: function(data){}`